# OpenCV Point Type Conversion

Tags: c++, opencv, point

OpenCV docs indicate that within the Point class there is a member function which can convert between data types (int --> float, etc). Docs advertise the following function for "conversion to another data type".

```
cv::Point_< _Tp >::operator Point_< _Tp2 > () const
```

I have not been able to get this to work. I have tried the following.

```
cv::Point2i test(0,0);
cv::Point2f out;

test.Point <Point2f>;
```

or

```
cv::Point2i test(0,0);
cv::Point2f out;

test.operator Point<Point2f>;
```

Has anyone been able to use this function?

Comment: That's a conversion function, use a cast

Comment: Simply `out = test;`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's an example of a [user-defined conversion function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cast_operator). You invoke it using a cast.

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

int main()
{
    cv::Point2i foo(1, 2);
    cv::Point2f bar;

    bar = static_cast<cv::Point2f>(foo);

    std::cout << foo << "\n" << bar << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
[1, 2]
[1, 2]
```

Comment: Thanks Dan, this works perfectly. I figured there was an easy way to take advantage of this function. I was able to achieve the same result by manually equating each one of the variables, but this is much cleaner. And now I have my first introduction to casts!